# $I_n=\int_0^{\infty} |f_n(t)|^2 t^2 dt < \infty \implies I_n \to \infty $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Let $g_n:[0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable functions, and $|g_n(n)| \geq 1$ for $n\in \mathbb N.$  Assume  that $g_n \neq g_m $ for $n\neq m.$

Put $f_n(t)=g'_n(t)$ for $t\in [0, \infty).$  Assume that $A_n= \{t\in [0, \infty): f_n(t)=0 \} \subset \mathbb N$ for all $n\in \mathbb N,$ and $I_n=\int_0^{\infty} |f_n(t)|^2 t^2 dt < \infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

> Question: Can we say $\{I_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is unbounded in $\mathbb R$?

Note: For instance,  $g_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}$ satisfies the above situation.

Comment: can't the $g_n$ just all be the same function? in this case, clearly $I_n$ does not diverge

Comment: @Bananach: On the contrary, in that case the sequence $(I_n)$ is constant, therefore convergent (provided that $I_0 < \infty$, of course, which is the crux of the problem).

Comment: so doesn't this contradict the conjecture that $(I_n)$ is always unbounded?

Comment: @Bananach: Thanks. I have edited my question.

Comment: @abcd assuming that the functions are not the same won't fix this. you can just add minor differences to them, and you'll still get an almost constant sequence that in particular does not diverge

Comment: @Bananach: Does there exists single $g_1$ such that $g_n(x)=g_1(x)$  for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $g_{1}(n)\geq 1$,  for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and satisfies the above hypothesis?

Comment: @Bananach: I guess, If $g_1(n) \geq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N,$ then $\int_0^{\infty} g_1(t)t^2 dt$ may not be finite .... Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: you are right, I missed that this one condition is actually different for different $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Let $f(x) = e^{-x^2/2} \sin \pi x$ and $g(x) = 1 + \int_0^x f(s) \, ds$. Set $g_n(x) = g(x - n)$. Then the set of $I_n$ is clearly bounded by 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}(\sin \pi x)^2 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{4} e^{-\pi ^2} \sqrt{\pi } \left(-1+e^{\pi ^2}+2 \pi ^2\right)
$$

**Correction**

For the functions chosen above, the $I_n$ are in fact **not** bounded. Here is a modification.

Let $f$ be defined as before. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let 
$J_n = \int_0^\infty |f(x-n)|^2 x^2 dx$. Now set
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{f(x-n)}{\sqrt{J_n}} \, .
$$
Then $\int_0^\infty |f_n(x)|^2 x^2 dx = 1$. And then define
$$
g_n(x) = 1 + \int_n^x f_n(s) \, ds \, .
$$
That should do it.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me what is domain of $g$? [My confusion: If $x<0$, how does $\int_0^xf(s) ds$ make sense? For $x>0,$ and we can choose $n$ large so $x_n<0$. Please correct me if I have missed something...]

Comment: @abcd: That is not a problem: if $x<0$, then $\int _0 ^x$ simply means $-\int _x ^0$.

Comment: @HansEngler: For simplicity, I would have bounded $\sin^2 (\pi x)$ by $1$.

Comment: @Hans Engler: Why $I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x-n)^2} \sin^2 \pi (n-x) x^2 dx \leq \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \sin^{2} (\pi t)  t^2 dt$?

Comment: @Hans Engler:  It clear to me that, by change of variable, $I_n \leq \int_{-n}^{\infty} e^{t^2} \sin^2(\pi t) (n+t)^2 dt $ (Just by taking, $n-x=t$ in the $I_n$). I guess, the factor $(n+t)^2$ creates trouble... to get upper bound... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AlexM.: Thanks. But think there is an another problem.  How to bound $I_n$? If we do change of variable then $(n+t)$ factor will appear...: Please correct me if I have missed some thing... Thanks.

Comment: @abcd: Your remark is correct, Hans will have to revisit his answer. I believe that he has simply forgotten about the "$-n$" part. This, unfortunately, seems to ruin the whole (otherwise ingenious) argument.

Comment: @abcd: Indeed, the answer has to be revised. See below.