# $\int_0^{\infty} |g_n(t)|^6 t^2 dt < \infty \implies I_n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $g_n:[0, \infty)\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable functions, and $|g_n(n)| \geq 1$ for $n\in \mathbb N.$   Assume that $\int_0^{\infty} |g_n(t)|^6 t^2 dt < \infty$ for each fixed $n.$ ...(A)

Assume that $I_n=\int_0^{\infty} |g'_n(t)|^2 t^2 dt < \infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

Define $h_n(n):= (g_n(n+1)-g_n(n))^2, n\in \mathbb N$

> Question: (1) Can we expect  $I_n \to \infty$? (2) What can we say about the  behavior $h_n$ at $\infty$?  Can we say $\lim_{n\to \infty} h_n(n) >c$ for some $c>0$?

Note: (1) For instance, $f_n(x)=e^{(n-x)^2}$ satisfies the above situation. (2) If we drop condition $(A)$, then the answer to (1) is negative. (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190734/i-n-int-0-infty-f-nt2-t2-dt-infty-implies-i-n-to-infty/2190853?noredirect=1#comment4509018_2190853))

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @uniquesolution: Thanks.  $h_n(n)\geq  g^2_n(n+1) -2g_n(n)g_n(n+1) +1$,  I guess, limit (limit inf or lim sup) will  be positive.  But I do not know how to use  hypothesis effectively... (I think, $g_n(t)  \to  0 $as $t \to \infty$)

Comment: @uniquesolution: Can you suggests something...?  Any remark or comments. Thanks.

Comment: Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, one can show $h_n (n) \leq I_n / n^2$. Hence, unless $I_n \gtrsim n^2$ for large $n $, you will always have $h_n (n) \to 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thanks.  In fact, I want to show that $I_n \to \infty $? (Can we expect this?  Can you say something? Any remark or comments.)  (It is clear to me that, $I_n \geq n^2 h_n(n) =n^2 (1-2 g_n(n+1) g_n(n)+ g^2_n(n+1))$, but from this I am unable to proceed .... )

Comment: @abcd: I think I can show that $I_n \geq n $, but this does not really answer the current question, since this still leaves the possibility that $I_n /n^2 \to 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Please would you tell me how to show $I_n\geq n$?  See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192088/int-0-infty-g-nt6-t2-dt-infty-i-n-int-0-infty-g-nt2-t2?rq=1) Thanks..

Comment: @PhoemueX: I have also edited my question. Thanks..

Comment: @abcd: Unfortunately, your other question was deleted (not by me). But I will post the proof as a comment on this thread later.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Fine. Thanks.  That question is   to show: $I_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$ I am very keen to see this.... Thanks a lot:

Comment: @abcd: It is well-known that if $\int_0^\infty g(t) dt < \infty$, then $g(t+n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for almost all $t$. Thus, by condition (A), we can find some $t$ with $|g_n (t+\ell)|^6 (t+\ell)^2 \to 0$, which implies $g_n (t+\ell) \to 0$ as $\ell \to \infty$. Now, the fundamental theorem of calculus shows $1 \leq |g_n(n)| = \lim_\ell |g_n (t+\ell) - g_n(n)| = \lim_\ell |\int_n^{t+\ell} g_n '(s) ds| \leq \int_n^\infty |g_n '(s)| s / s ds$. By Hölder's inequality, we get $1 \leq \int_n^\infty |g_n'(s)|^2 s^2 ds \cdot \int_n^\infty s^{-2} ds$. This should allow you to conclude $I_n \geq n$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Wow!  This is very helpful, and solution is too good. Indeed, thanks... a lot: